# Ubuntu 12.04 ping 8.8.8.8 does not work on one network only

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, dns, ping

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.
I can connect to and use the internet on one wireless network (say A) and not on the other network (say B). 
I can connect to B and get an IP address.
When I ping 127.0.0.1 it works 
When I ping 192.168.1.1 it also works 
but when I ping 8.8.8.8 I get destination host unreachable.

I tried commenting out dns=dnsmasq in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf but that didn't work and then restarting the network manager.

I also tried to flush the cache using ip route flush cache but that also did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The other network (network B) most probably has a **firewall** implemented, which is configured to block ICMP packets (pings). This is most likely the case if the network is in a university, at work, or maybe even a (smart) coffee shop.

When you `ping 8.8.8.8`, an IP should be mentioned in that message you got. I'm betting that that IP is 192.168.1.1, so the error would be something like `reply: 192.168.1.1 destination host unreachable`. Also, to be more certain, you can do a **traceroute**. This shows you the path that your ping travels, so we can find exactly where it stops. So, if you run the command `traceroute -n 8.8.8.8`, you'll probably get something like this:

<sub>I think you might need to install traceroute using `sudo apt-get install traceroute`.</sub>

```
alaa@aa-UBUNTU:~$ traceroute -n 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1  1.204 ms  1.953 ms  2.101 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
```

...and those stars will just keep on coming. This means that your ping went to 192.168.1.1, but then it stopped, it hit a wall, so you'll never be able to ping 8.8.8.8.

Also, this has nothing to do with DNS, because you're pinging an IP, not a hostname like google.com. DNS is a system that merely translates the words `google.com` to something like `74.125.236.105`. If there was something wrong with your DNS settings, `ping google.com` would return something like this: `ping: unknown host google.com`, but `ping 8.8.8.8` would not, because you're already pinging a direct IP.

<sub>I suggest you revert the changes you made to NetworkManager.conf.</sub>

Comment: Hey Alaa 
I did do what you said. Here are the results:

'traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets

 1  * * *

 2  * * *

 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *

17  192.168.1.1  9.008 ms !N * *
'

Comment: Yes, this means that in network B, `192.168.1.1` is blocking your pings, because it has some kind of firewall implemented. After re-reading your question though, what is your main issue? Is it that you can't `ping 8.8.8.8`, or that you can't access the internet (that is, you can't browse anything)?

Comment: Its both. 
I can neither ping 8.8.8.8 nor access the internet. 
Cant do a sudo apt-get if that helps. 
Network B is actually my home network and A is my school network. 
I guess I need to call comcast ?

Comment: One last question. What is the output of `route -n`?

Comment: The problem seems to have magically fixed itself atleast for now. Thank you Alaa

Comment: It was most likely an issue from comcast. Anyways, you're welcome!